# Google chart API is not displaying the chart using javascript/ajax

Tags: php, google-visualization

What I am doing is to display a graph when a user clicks a button. The chart is being fetched from a PHP file using javascript. Here is the code what i am actually doing.

This is the javascript function that fetches graph and attaches it to HTML DOM

```
function draw_graph(num) {

   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else { // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var output = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('script_content').innerHTML = output;
       }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/getgraphdata.php?type="+num+"&mode=day",true);
   xmlhttp.send();

}
```

This is the PHP code, I am trying to draw a simple graph with dummy data

```
    <?php

echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">                   
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {
                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'Sell');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'Purchase');
                            data.addRows([
                              ['12-03-2012', 150, 300],
                              ['12-04-2012', 250, 500]
                            ]);

                            var options = {
                              title: 'Graph'
                            };
                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart.(document.getElementById('temp'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        }
                    </script>
    ";
```

The above code attached with the HTML DOM correctly, but graph is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart.(document.getElementById('temp'));
```

Remove `.` after `LineChart`. Hence, it is `LineChart(document.getElementById('temp'));`

Also place an `alert("statement reached");` between the above line and the next line to track the error. If the error takes place, next line may not get executed, and thus use it as a debug advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried that before, you can't include text javascript code using ajax.

If you really want to do it that way you have to [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) the responseText string or have the javascript do something based on the string returned.

eg.

```
if(responseText == '1'){
 function1();
}else{
 function2();
}
```

Is there any reason you can't just include the php file instead?

```
<?php
require_once 'googleapi.php';
?>
```